# vscode navigation find references not working on a react project

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working on a react project which has file names ending with .js, .tsx.  However VSCode find references does not work on these files.  It seems to work only on .ts files.  Is there something I need to do in order to get this working?